# How to do a FOR or loop that start on X and end Y index of a list on Django Template Languge?

Tags: django, django-templates

For example i have a list of 10 objects but i just want to get last 5 or the first 5 objects.

```
{% for x in objects %}
.....first 5 objects......
{% endfor %}

{% for x in objects %}
.....last 5 objects......
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First method ([`forloop.counter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#for)):

```
{% for x in objects %}
    {% if forloop.counter <= 5 %}
        access first 5 objects
    {% else %}
        access last 5 objects
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Second method:

```
# views.py

def my_view(request):
    first_five_obj = MyModel.objects.all()[:5]
    last_five_obj = MyModel.objects.all()[-5:]
    return render(request, 'template.html', locals())

<!-- template.html -->

{% for x in first_five_obj %}
    .....first 5 objects......
{% endfor %}

{% for x in last_five_obj %}
    .....last 5 objects......
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks i like more the first method whitout the else and i will add other for loop with this condition {% if forloop.counter > 5 %}

Answer (score 1):

- You could consider using a custom template tag.
- Could loop through objects:

  ```
  {% for x in objects %}
      {% if forloop.counter <= 5 %}
          # ....do something....
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% for x in objects %}
      {% if forloop.revcounter <= 5 %}
          # ....do something....
      {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  ```
- You could get the items directly (Assuming the length of objects doesn't change when displaying last 5 in list.):

  ```
  {{ objects.0 }}
  {{ objects.1 }}
  {{ objects.2 }}
  ...
  {{ objects.7 }}
  {{ objects.8 }}
  {{ objects.9 }}
  ```

Comment: The second one it help me to other things that i was developing, but noticed tha it was more slow the performance of tha page, but thanks.